# Is there any difference in pronounciation between these two?

Tags: quran, arabic, quran-recitation

In [Surah Al-Baqarah verse 234,](https://quran.com/2/234) this appears:

[image: فِيمَا]

Then in [verse 240,](https://quran.com/2/240) this appears:

[image: في مَا]

Is there any difference in the pronounciation of them?

Answer (score 3):

I am a native arabic speaker. No, there is no difference in the pronounciation of them.
you can listen to an automatic voice using the voice icon in google translator:

[image]

test it [here](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ar&tl=en&text=%D9%81%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7%0A%D9%81%D9%90%D9%8A%20%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7).

<sub>**if you use the Arabic diacritics, you will get a good automatic pronociation.**</sub>